# UPS, when click on "Edit My Profile" for 1 user I got an exception

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, fast-search, ad

I am using sp2010. When I go to CA en go to the User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Profiles -> search on a username like domainA\joha I got one result. When I click on the user I click on the link "Edit My Profile". Now I got this error on the screen with an correlation id:

> Error  An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 8b21dcf2-b71c-429a-a28e-905e70aa5451
>
> Date and Time: 26/08/2014 17:26:51
>
> Go back to site

After searching for this correlation id in the ULS log I found this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileUI.SetReferer()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileUI.LoadControl(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)      at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)      at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

When I do this for another user everything is working fine. There is also something else trange with this user. In sharepoint normaly you see the displayname like here:

[image]

For this user you dont see the displayname but the username "domainA\joha". The user exist in AD. I did an full sync of the people content source.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the user from UPS. I did a full sync in UPS. After this I did a full crawl. Now it is fixed :)